# Non progress dialoge or Alert message be showed in my fragement

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I have class that extend `FragmentActivity` in it I add fragment to layout as following

```
public class maincontrolActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maincontrol);

                  oUnit fragment = new  oUnit();
                  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragment, "MY_FRAG");
                  fragmentTransaction.commit();

}


}
```

the Ounit is look like

```
public class oUnit  extends Fragment {
         View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.chemounit,
                container,
                false);
```

///// my other code

```
 return view;
}
```

`oCreateView` in `Ounit` I try to add progress bar like

```
     ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog( getActivity());
      connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
      connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
      connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
      connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Leads...");
      connectionProgressDialog.show();
```

but it never show

I have in this fragement list I path to its constructor context using `view.getContext()`

I try to display `AlertDialog`

```
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                final EditText input = new EditText(v.getContext());
               alert.setView(input);
               alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                  //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s_spin_text,
                        //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                   }
           });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                   }
                   });
           alert.show();
```

is this problems due to this line

```
     View view = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.chemounit,
                container,
                false);
```

if yes ? how to replace it

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to do this you should use: [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

There you have method `OnCreateDialog()`
and there you can put your code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final ProgressDialog connectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog( getActivity());
  connectionProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
  connectionProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  connectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Leads...");
  connectionProgressDialog
  return connectionProgressDialog;
}
```